# SQL Server find unique combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique

I have a table

```
rate_id  service_id
1        1
1        2
2        1
2        3
3        1
3        2
4        1
4        2
4        3
```

I need to find and insert in a table the unique combinations of sevice_ids by rate_id...but when the combination is repeated in another rate_id I do not want it to be inserted

In the above example there are 3 combinations
`1,2`  `1,3`  `1,2,3`

How can I query the first table to get the unique combinations?

Thanx!

Comment: So result will be stored as comma separated values? And with no reference to rate_id?

Comment: What about the value `4` and why does it not appear anywhere in your expected output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the combinations are the `GROUP_CONCAT` of `service_id` for each `rate_id`

Comment: @sagi I imagined as much, but his sample should show this.

Comment: @Ivan I do not need the rate_id. I want to spot the unique combinations

Comment: Are you using a programming language with SQL Server?  I feel this might be easier to handle in the app layer.

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2014. I need to do it purely with SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE ([rate_id] INT, [service_id] INT)

INSERT INTO @TempTable
VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3)

SELECT DISTINCT
    --[rate_id], --include if required
    (
    SELECT
        CAST(t2.[service_id] AS VARCHAR) + ' '
    FROM
        @TempTable t2
    WHERE
        t1.[rate_id] = t2.[rate_id]
    ORDER BY
        t2.[rate_id]
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) AS 'Combinations'
FROM 
    @TempTable t1
```

I put the values in a table variable just for ease of testing the SELECT query.

Comment: excelent query but it still displays combinations more than once.

Comment: Sorry @PanosPlat I misread, I thought you wanted distinct values per rate ID. I'll amend the above to remove that field from the result set then.

Comment: @Paul Andrew, you must have `ORDER BY` in the `FOR XML` sub-query otherwise it does not work. To test put "(1,2)," as first value. Otherwise good answer.

Comment: Thanks @Alex I've amended it.